# a duplicate video finder: need to know what encoder preset was used

Tags: batch-file, video, batch-processing, libx265

this script looks for duplicate videos by filename. Filenames are all formatted
`Video Title (YEAR#) other info.mkv`.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /a-d') do set "compare=%cd%\%%v" & call :action
exit /b

:action

:: if already moved do next file
if not exist "%compare%" exit /b

:: extrapolate search string by cutting after year tag
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%y in (1900,1,2100) do set "string=!compare:(%%y)=(%%y)&rem !"
endlocal & set string=%string%

:: count similar files within folder 
set "count=0" & set "report="
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('where ".:%string%*" 2^>nul') do set /a "count+=1" && set "report=%string:?= %"

:: what happens for duplicates
if not "%count%"=="0" if not "%count%"=="1" echo duplicates found %report%
if not "%count%"=="0" if not "%count%"=="1" for /f "delims=" %%v in ('where ".:%string%*" 2^>nul') do move "%%v" d:\dupes
```

it is currently set to move duplicates for manual comparison and delete. what would really help me out with this (manual processing or auto-deletion) is knowing what (x265) codec `preset` they were encoded with. I can't find this info using `mediainfo`. how can I spot the sloppy encodes?

Comment: Are you talking about the encoding profile, such as "fast" or similar?  You could use `ffprobe` to get all sorts of easily scrapeable video statistics.  Example: `ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries "stream=profile" -of flat videofile.exe`.  If "profile" isn't what you're after, then remove `=profile` from the above string to see all `stream` statistics.  Maybe one of the stats dumped that way will be what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think the profile is it. I just keep getting `Main 10` in every file I tried. I was hoping to find one of these possible `presets` called `ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow` and `placebo`. but since using a preset is not needed (custom settings can be used) I guess we need an other way of spotting fast encodes.